# Atomic Reference Not Changing

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, textfield, atomicreference

My Atomic Reference is not changing when the user inputs an expression of numbers. I think it has something to do with the lines inside of my Verify button event handler at `card1.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(0)` but I'm not sure how to fix this. I tried placing `deck.get(0).CardValue()` but the method isn't working for that. Could I place my deck somewhere else to make this work? Here is my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class Main extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


      ArrayList<Integer> deck;
      deck = new ArrayList<>();
      int i = 1;
      while(i < 52){
         deck.add(i);
         i++;
      }
      final AtomicReference<String> result = new AtomicReference<>("go.");

      Collections.shuffle(deck);

      BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

      HBox top = new HBox(10);
      Label display = new Label(result.toString());
      Button btShuffle = new Button("Shuffle");

      top.getChildren().add(display);
      top.getChildren().add(btShuffle);


      HBox center = new HBox(10);
      Card card1 = new Card(deck.get(0));
      center.getChildren().add(card1);

      Card card2 = new Card(deck.get(1));
      center.getChildren().add(card2);

      Card card3 = new Card(deck.get(12));
      center.getChildren().add(card3);

      Card card4 = new Card(deck.get(14));
      center.getChildren().add(card4);



      btShuffle.setOnAction(
            e -> {
               Collections.shuffle(deck);
              center.getChildren().clear();    
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(0)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(1)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(2)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(3)));

            });





      HBox bottom = new HBox(10);
      Label expression = new Label("Please Enter the expression: ");

      TextField tfExpress = new TextField();
      ArrayList<Character> signs = new ArrayList<>();
      signs.add('/');
      signs.add('+');
      signs.add('(');
      signs.add(')');
      signs.add('-');
      signs.add('^');
      signs.add('*');
      signs.add('%');
      String str = tfExpress.getText();


      int express = (str != null && !"".equals(str)) ? Integer.parseInt(str) : -1;      



     // expInput.removeIf(p-> p.equals(signs));

      Button btVerify = new Button("Verify");
      bottom.getChildren().add(expression);
      bottom.getChildren().add(tfExpress);
      bottom.getChildren().add(btVerify);

      btVerify.setOnAction(
            (ActionEvent e) -> 
            {
               LinkedList<Character> expInput = new LinkedList<Character>();
            for(char c: tfExpress.getText().toCharArray()){
                expInput.add(c);
                }

               expInput.removeIf(p-> p.equals(signs));


               if(card1.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(0)
               && card2.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(1)
               && card3.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(2)
               && card4.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(3))
               {
                  if(express == 24){
                     result.set("Correct");
                  }
                  else
                     result.set("Incorrect");

               }
               else
                  result.set("The numbers in the expression don't "
                     + "match the numbers in the set.");
            });



      pane.setTop(top);
      pane.setCenter(center);
      pane.setBottom(bottom);

      Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
      primaryStage.setTitle("24 card game");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
   }

   public class Card extends Pane {
      public int cardVal;
      Card(int card){
         Image cardImage;
         cardImage = new Image("card/"+ card +".png");
         getChildren().add(new ImageView(cardImage));
         cardVal = card;

      }

      public int CardValue(){
         int card = 0;

         if(cardVal <= 13){
            card = cardVal;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 13 && cardVal <= 26){
            card = cardVal - 13;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 26 && cardVal <= 39){
            card = cardVal - 26;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 39 && cardVal <= 52){
            card = cardVal - 39;
         }


         return card;
      }




   }



   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried marking the result as non-final `AtomicReference<String> result = new AtomicReference<>("go.");` ?

Comment: yes I did try this, it produces the same result.

Comment: Do you really mean the `result` attribute which does not change or the text of your `display` label which is initialized with `result.toString` but never updated?

Comment: yes I definitely mean to change the text of that label. So I cannot change this by changing result?

Comment: Changing `result` does not change the text of your label to update the label use `display.setText(..)` instead.

Comment: Thank you I just fixed that actually. My problem now is much bigger as I think I have a major flaw in my code logic. The program cannot recognize the number values for the cards being displayed. I think this may have something to do with the line of code I posted above `card1.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(0)`